# Объединить коллекции

Tags: c#, коллекции

Есть три коллекции:

```
var family = from account in json["accounts"] select account["fname"].Value<string>();
var name = from account in json["accounts"] select account["iname"].Value<string>();
var email = from account in json["accounts"] select account["login"].Value<string>();
```

Пробовал через Linq, но там можно максимум две

```
var result = family.Zip(name, (f, n) => new { family = f, name = n});
```

Как мне их в одну объединить?

Comment: что именно вы хотите получить? Также что из себя представляют 'bnb три коллекции?

Comment: Хочу Foreach вывести все в Gridview. Коллекции это выборка по JSON файлу

Comment: Gridview и foreach отношения к вопросу не имеют. Каким должен быть результат? И что это за выборки? У вас слишком расплывчатый вопрос

Comment: Как мне соединить все три коллекции как в случаи с Linq. Хочу обращаться к полям по именам.

Comment: Хотите получить ответ - приведите пример исходных данных и результирующей коллекции

Comment: foreach (var one in result)
        {
            DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();

            dtrow["#"] = i;
            dtrow["Фамилия"] = one.family;
            dtrow["Имя"] = one.name;
            

            dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
            i++;
        }

Comment: @shatoidil вы русский язык понимаете? Приведите пример данных, которые хотите преобразовывать, приведите пример результата, который ожидаете увидеть. Все эти ваши DataRow и GridView здесь смысла не имеют

Comment: Суть вопроса, можно ли их так же объеденить, как и две коллекции?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый шаг сделан:

```
var result = family.Zip(name, (f, n) => new { family = f, name = n});
```

И никто не мешает продолжить:

```
var result = family
    .Zip(name, (f, n) => new { family = f, name = n })
    .Zip(email, (f, e) => new { f.family, f.name, email = e });
```

Но почему бы не сразу:

```
var result=from account in json["accounts"] 
select new 
{
  family=account["fname"].Value<string>(), 
  name=account["iname"].Value<string>(), 
  email=account["login"].Value<string>()
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var res = from account in json["accounts"] select new
{
  Family = account["fname"].Value<string>(),
  Name = account["iname"].Value<string>(),
  Email = account["login"].Value<string>()
};
```